# Lambda returning 200 even though exception was thrown

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, exception, java-8, aws-lambda

I have the following code deployed in an AWS Lambda:

```
public class MyTrigger implements RequestHandler<Request, Void> {

    private final Service service = new Service();

    @Override
    public Void handleRequest(Request request, Context context) {
        service.process(request);
        return null;
    }
}
```

and the `.process()` method is throwing an `IllegalStateException`.

This lambda is triggered "manually" with the following code:

```
public class LambdaUtils {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LambdaUtils.class);

    public static Integer invoke(String functionName, String payload) {
        log.info("Invoking lambda {} with payload {}", functionName, payload);
        final AWSLambdaAsync lambdaClient = AWSLambdaAsyncClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(Regions.EU_WEST_1).build();
        final InvokeRequest request = new InvokeRequest();
        request.withFunctionName(functionName).withPayload(payload);
        final InvokeResult invokeResult = lambdaClient.invoke(request);
        final Integer statusCode = invokeResult.getStatusCode();
        log.info("Invoked lambda. Got status code {} and payload {}", statusCode, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.decode(invokeResult.getPayload()).toString());
        return statusCode;
    }
}
```

The problem is that, even though an exception is thrown inside the lambda the status code is 200 anyway:
`Invoked lambda. Got status code 200 and payload [... stacktrace ...]`.

I am using the following dependency to create the client and perform the invocation:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-lambda</artifactId>
    <version>1.11.297</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

The 200 has nothing to do with the actual lambda result or the actual invocation of the lambda itself. If you would get basically anything other than a 200 that would mean the lambda invocation could not be accepted, which means that your lambda would not get invoked at all.

From [AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_Invoke.html):

> The status code in the API response doesn't reflect function errors. Error codes are reserved for errors that prevent your function from executing, such as permissions errors, limit errors, or issues with your function's code and configuration. For example, Lambda returns TooManyRequestsException if executing the function would cause you to exceed a concurrency limit at either the account level (ConcurrentInvocationLimitExceeded) or function level (ReservedFunctionConcurrentInvocationLimitExceeded).

Comment: Even though the client is Async, why are there `.invokeAsync` methods? My invoke is waiting for the execution to be completed and it is not returning a Future like the `invokeAsycn()` is returning. I will give a try to the not AsyncClient though.

Comment: I have tried your solution but the result is the same. After reading your response I am not even sure what I want is possible.

Comment: @burm87 wait, you actually get the stacktrace in the payload? Then everything is good. You should simply not return the stacktrace alone but wrap it in JSON and add a field that makes it clear this was an error.

Comment: @luk2302 The question is: **if the call is sync** (it returns the result in the body) **and it is throwing an exception** (the stack trace is in the body), then **why does the AWS SDK register it as success anyway** (status 200)? I've also found this behavior where a lambda throws an exception but the execution shows as a success in AWS logs, and this throws some helper apps like Dashbird off.

Comment: @luk2302 yes I could do that and create my own response, but I was hoping there was something builtin in the library.

Comment: @walen I think it is because, as luk2302 said, the 200 is not referring to the correct execution of the lambda method, but to the correct invocation of the lambda.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is a couple of years old, but I landed here with the same problem and found a solution! According to the documentation on [Lambda function errors in Java](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-exceptions.html):

> A 2xx series error with a X-Amz-Function-Error header in the response indicates a Lambda runtime or function error. A 2xx series status code indicates that Lambda accepted the request, but instead of an error code, Lambda indicates the error by including the X-Amz-Function-Error header in the response.

So in addition to checking the `HTTPStatusCode`, you also need to check whether a `x-amz-function-error` header is present in the returned `HTTPHeaders`. This is working for my Python application and I would assume the response format is the same in Java.